# Aggregate Feeds for Answers & Comments

Tags: feature-request, feed

Is it possible to have feeds for answers in posts in aggregate form? Right now you can view answers by viewing the feed for the specific question, and comments only by viewing a users feed (If there are other ways let me know). There is a lot of unnecessary traffic to check to see if answers were posted for several questions. Also there is no easy method of finding comments on posts, an aggregate feed of all comments could solve this.

Personally I would use this information for indexing. These feeds could greatly improve the data we have access to, and could lead to user driven API's before a real API is released.