# Best way to keep track of comments in questions

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I have been reading some past answers from as far back as 2011. But I wanted to see if anything new has changed.

When you see a question that you need clarification from you usually post a comment. For me I assumed that once that is done I will get notified when there is activity on that question... but I was sadly mistaken!

After a bit of reading it seem comments are not really activity, so the only way is to tag the question as a favorite...

Is there a better way?

Comment: In way are you asking about being "notified"?

Comment: Actually even favorites track only "real" activity like edits or bounties and question feed doesn't include comments. Your best bet is just keep an eye over the question timeline on regular basis and you can clearly see there when new comments are posted. [Example for a timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/194703/timeline). [Details about timeline in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view).

Comment: Like in the StackExchange "inbox" or such... or if you make a comment then it should be added to some list on your profile where you see all questions on which you have commented on (if that exists), then you can sort by newest/activity...

Comment: Related: [Is there a feed for Stack Overflow that also has comments in RSS?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36738/is-there-a-feed-for-stack-overflow-that-also-has-comments-in-rss), [Aggregate Feeds for Answers & Comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/aggregate-feeds-for-answers-comments).

Comment: You can also install [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app), but not sure if it's still working. Try at your own risk... :)

Comment: Very useful feedback guys, thanks :) regarding "install this"... I would if I could but my IT guys are really anal and I am not allow to even pick my nose without an IT request! (bit off topic, but feels good to vent!)

Comment: @code_fodder I feel your pain... in the future please use `@` to reply, otherwise people won't see your comment.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard sorry, I literally just learned that from the answer below... not sure if it worked. Does it work for names with spaces? (I just did "@Sha Wiz Dow Ard) at the start of this post.

Comment: Cheers, we all learn at some point. :) As for your question the answer is no, spaces should be removed but in this case it worked because it's enough to type the first three letters after `@` to trigger the notification (so `@Sha` was enough, the rest is just letters :)). When you type the first letter after `@` you should see "auto complete" pop up though so just select the name there and spaces will get auto removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tag someone in a comment (by using @TheirUserName), they will get notified.  Most people will, similarly, tag you if they make a comment that they want to make sure you see.

Also, if you go to your activity page, you can see activity on questions or answers you have posted by looking at the "Responses" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a better way now. Since 2020, as explained in [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/1242908) post, the best way to be informed about new comments is to follow the post by clicking the [follow] button shown in the menu immediately below the post next to the [Flag] button.